# Pythonnet Multiple python instances in message handling

Tags: python, c#, multithreading, masstransit, python.net

I have a c# application that handles Messages and need to call python code for each message received. But if i run the Processing in parallel my docker container dies with a 139 exit code. How can i run the python code for each method in a seperate python context?

MessageHandler:

```
public class ProcessingConsumer : IConsumer<DumbClassOne>
{
  private readonly ILogger<ProcessingConsumer> _logger;

  public ProcessingConsumer(ILogger<ProcessingConsumer> logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DumbClassOne> context)
  {
    
    _logger.LogInformation("---Handling event----");

    using (new PythonEngine())
    {
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            using (var scope = Py.CreateScope(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
            {
                dynamic py = scope;
                py.Exec(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("run.py"));
                // Redirect Python logs to .NET Core logger
                dynamic pythonLogger = py.logger;
                dynamic handler = new DotNetLogHandler(_logger);
                pythonLogger.addHandler(handler);
                py.log_something();
                pythonLogger.removeHandler(handler);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create `PythonEngine` every time. Create it once at the program launch. Shutting it down all the time without a dire need to do so is not a good idea and only 1 instance at time is supported anyway.

Comment: ok thx for the answer. So there is no way to get a seperate instances of python for each message ?

Comment: @muhmuhhum why do you need a separate instance of Python? The best way may be starting a new process.